# Python cv2.warpPerspective 3D rotate

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have problem with understanding rotate matrix in cv2.warpPerspective function. I wrote this program:

```
import cv2, math
import numpy as np

def translation_mat(dx, dy):
    return np.array([1,0,dx,   0,1,dy,   0,0,1]).reshape((3,3))

def anglesToRotationMatrix(angles, image_size) :
    # convert angle in radians
    rangle = np.deg2rad(angles)
    # calculate middle of image
    t1 = translation_mat(-image_size[1]/2, -image_size[0]/2)
    t2 = translation_mat( image_size[1]/2, image_size[0]/2 )

    R_x = np.array([[1,         0,                   0                     ],
                    [0,         math.cos(rangle[0]),  -math.sin(rangle[0]) ],
                    [0,         math.sin(rangle[0]),  math.cos(rangle[0])  ]
                    ])

    R_y = np.array([[math.cos(rangle[1]) ,   0,      math.sin(rangle[1])   ],
                    [0                   ,   1,      0                     ],
                    [-math.sin(rangle[1]),   0,      math.cos(rangle[1])   ]
                    ])

    R_z = np.array([[math.cos(rangle[2]),    -math.sin(rangle[2]),        0],
                    [math.sin(rangle[2]),    math.cos(rangle[2]) ,        0],
                    [0                  ,    0                   ,        1]
                    ])

    R = np.dot( t2.dot(R_z.dot(t1)), np.dot( t2.dot(R_y.dot(t1)), t2.dot(R_x.dot(t1)) ) )

    return R

def rotateImageByDegrees(input_image, angles) :
    # calculate warp matrix
    warp_matrix = anglesToRotationMatrix(angles, input_image.shape)
    print warp_matrix
    #im_aligned = cv2.warpPerspective (input_image, warp_matrix, (input_image.shape[1], input_image.shape[0]), flags=cv2.INTER_LINEAR, borderValue=(255, 255, 255) )
    rotated_image = cv2.warpPerspective (input_image, warp_matrix, (input_image.shape[1], input_image.shape[0]), flags=cv2.INTER_LINEAR )
    return rotated_image

if __name__ == '__main__':
    im =  cv2.imread("Lenna.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
    im_aligned = rotateImageByDegrees(im, [-0.1, 0.0,   0])

    # Show final output
    cv2.imshow("original", im)
    cv2.imshow("rotated", im_aligned)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I'm expecting that function rotateImageByDegrees(im, [-0.1, 0.0,   0]) should rotate image only in one axis by really small degree angle, but change in image [is quite big](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpYyN.png). But for axis Z all works fine [(i.e. image is rotated by 45 degrees without any problems)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sI0r.png). Where I did mistake?

Comment: I'm a little confused, your rotation matrix shape is `(3,3)` from the above code, correct? You need a `(4,4)` perspective transform to warp points in three dimensions. I think the issue is with how you're adding the translation; it should go in the fourth column. See [here](http://jepsonsblog.blogspot.in/2012/11/rotation-in-3d-using-opencvs.html) for e.g.. The code is in C++ but translating it shouldn't be hard. It's the same thing you have but with an extra row and column of zeros (with a one in the last entry as usual).

Comment: I rewrote this code in Python, but I get error:

return cv2.warpPerspective (input_image, trans, (input_image.shape[1], input_image.shape[0]), flags=cv2.INTER_LINEAR )
cv2.error: C:\build\master_winpack-bindings-win32-vc14-static\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\imgwarp.cpp:6518: error: (-215) (M0.type() == CV_32F || M0.type() == CV
_64F) && M0.rows == 3 && M0.cols == 3 in function cv::warpPerspective

which IMO means that warpPerspective require (3,3) rotation matrix

Comment: Sorry---I wrote that hastily. It does require a `(3,3)` matrix but the translations and rotations make more sense with a `(4,4)` and then transformed into a `(3,3)` matrix. You can see in that blog that he does a 2d-to-3d transformation and then back from 3d-to-2d transformation to pass (using `(3,4)` and `(4,3)` matrices to do the conversion). I didn't see your `translation_mat` function and so I was mostly confused with your translations. I'll try and take a whack with it.